# I have an error when I want to publish apk to the Google Play developer console

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I use Android Studio for development. When i finish the code source, I build and sign, but they tell me that your keystore is not correctly created, you have to convert it to pk20 so I use APK Signer to sign my APK. When I upload it to the console they told me this error :

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(471346): Bad resource table: header size 0x0 or total size 0x4b52 is not on an integer boundary
ERROR: dump failed because the resource table is invalid/corrup
```

Comment: Do you have the latest JDK and the latest Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your JDK for the latest version. It fixed the issue in my case.